# Load Python custom libraries to Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I started a project in Robot Framework and I have some issues with my custom libraries from python.

I have such structure:

[image: The file structure]

My problem now is that my Keywords (the ones inside Keywords directory) has dependencies on files from GeneralCommands directory and also from HelperClass.py and HelperClass2.py. If I run the code in Python, everything is fine. But when I call one of the keywords in Robot Framework with:

```
Library      ../../Common/Keywords/TestKeyword.py
```

it complains that it cannot find the dependencies:

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\(...)\test.robot': Importing test library 'C:\(...)\Common\Keywords\TestKeyword.py' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'GeneralCommand1'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\(...)\Common\Keywords\TestKeyword.py", line 5, in <module>
    from GeneralCommand1 import *
```

The only way I found to solve this was to add literally every single dependency inside the .robot file, like:

```
Library           ../../Common/HelperClass.py
Library           ../../Common/HelperClass2.py
Library           ../../Common/LmCommands/GeneralCommand1.py
Library           ../../Common/Keywords/TestKeyword.py
```

However this approach will become complicated to deal with when I will extend the custom libraries, in the end I will have dozens of import library lines.
I know there is such thing as the --pythonpath, but I want to avoid using it because this project will be in different machines and paths will not always be the same.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Create a robot file only with generic imports in a common directory

e.g. myImports.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary   
Library    Collections      
Library    DateTime   
Library    ../../Common/HelperClass.py
Library    ../../Common/HelperClass2.py
Library    ../../Common/LmCommands/GeneralCommand1.py
Library    ../../Common/Keywords/TestKeyword.py
```

Now myImports.robot can be imported to test suites

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    ../../Common/myImports.robot
```

Comment: This is actual one of the approaches I'm thinking about, but besides not having so much space taken away in the test suite file, I'm in the same situation - as in, if I extend the my custom libraries and consequently add more files/dependencies, I need to add them constantly to the myImports.robot file, which later on can get a bit messy.

Actually for me the only imports I need are the actual keywords (e.g. ../../Common/Keywords/TestKeyword.py), but it seems that Robot need the actual dependencies there as well